# CSS Regression testing with VCS and CI

Tags: css, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, regression-testing

BackstopJS generates a single page with regression test results. Is there any tool that works with CI (doesn't matter which one) and VCS (git) and assigns the test results to commits? I imagine the main page has a list of commits with passed/failed numbers next to them and links to a page with full results. Doesn't have to use BackstopJS.

Doesn't have to be as good as what I just described, I'd be happy for anything better than a script that copies results from BackstopJS to a folder with time and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be wanting to look into ‘pre commit hooks’ and working that into your build process. Might include a grunt-based git hook module and some bash scripting..

On projects I use CSS Regression testing it is still manual prior to commit/push.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks

http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/